# Plotting occurrences by date - Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a dataset of tweets made in this way:

```
mydata <- read.csv(header=TRUE, text='"tweet","Topic","created_at"
"text1","topic1","2020-08-13"
"text2","topic2","2020-08-11"
"text3","topic2","2020-08-11"
"text4","topic2","2020-08-10"
"text5","topic1","2020-08-13"
"text6","topic1","2020-08-14"
"text7","topic1","2020-08-15"')
```

I want to plot the occurrence of each topic over time day by day (for example, if on 2020-08-11 there have been 5 tweets belonging to topic 1 and 2 tweets belonging to topic 2, the value of topic 1 for that day will be 5 and for topic 2 will be 2, and so on), and I'm trying to do it with this code:

```
mydata%>%
  mutate(created_at = lubridate::ymd_hms(created_at), 
         date = as.Date(created_at)) %>%
  count(date, Topic) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, n, color = Topic)) + geom_line()+
  labs(y="n° tweets")
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number
```

What can I do?
My goal is a result like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`created_at` does not have the proper format for `lubridate::ymd_hms()` which creates `NA`-values in your dataset. You can simply remove it and use `as.Date()` and your code does what you want:

```
mydata %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(created_at)) %>%
  count(date, Topic) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, n, color = Topic)) + geom_line()+
  labs(y="n° tweets")
```

[image]